# What is the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.dll and where can I get the official ones from Microsoft?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vspackage, vssdk

I am looking for access to some functions in the DLL I mentioned above. I am not aware of any Nuget package that provides this DLLs.
So my question is, where do I get the latest version of this .dll from MS, and are they compatible with plugins targeting VS2019 and later?

Comment: That dll is probably for Window Management code ;). I can find mine for 2019 in the installation location under the Common7/IDE dir.

Comment: Did you search your C: drive? You may already have one. I found one here: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement\v4.0_14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.dll

Comment: It is a private assembly for Visual Studio, the only practical way to get it is to ask your user to install VS.  Which also ensures you got all of its dependencies.  Finding it back on the user's machine is not very practical since its storage location depends on the VS edition.  Microsoft also has no reason whatsoever to keep your program operating correctly when it updates VS.  So this is rather a bad idea.  Not explaining why you need to do this is a bad idea, stops anybody from proposing a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, I am new to stack-overflow and probably didn't explain myself better.
I am developing a Visual Studio Plugin which closes some Document Windows in VS. I found some repos of VS plugins on Github which has a reference to this .DLL, and they use it to close all clones of Document Windows by casting the `IVsWindowFrame` to `WindowFrame` class belonging to this DLL.

As pointed out in comments: I found the DLL in my C: drive under this path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE`